# Describe statement "Exactly k out of n variables should be true" in 2-SAT in time polynomial to n and k?

Tags: 2-sat

I have a list of $n$ variables, exactly $k$ of which should be true. Is it possible to encode this as a 2-SAT problem in time polynomial to $n$ and $k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x,y,z$ are three satisfying assignments of a 2SAT formula $\phi$, then the bitwise majority of $x,y,z$ is also a satisfying assignment $\phi$. To verify this, it suffices to check that this works for every clause of width 2.

If $n \geq k+2$, we can consider the following three assignments:

- $x_i = y_i = z_i = 1$ for $i = 1,\ldots,k-1$.
- $x_k = 1$, and all unspecified indices are $0$.
- $y_{k+1} = 1$, and all unspecified indices are $0$.
- $z_{k+2} = 1$, and all unspecified indices are $0$.

The majority of $x,y,z$ has only $k-1$ many $1$'s, and so when $n \geq k+2$, you cannot express your predicate in 2SAT at all. This still holds even if you allow extension variables, that is, if you allow formulas of the form $\phi(x,t)$ such that $\phi(x,t)$ holds for some $t$ iff at least $k$ of the $n$ variables in $x$ are true.

If $n = k+1$ and $k \geq 2$, we can consider the following three assignments:

- $x_i = y_i = z_i = 1$ for $i = 1,\ldots,k-2$.
- $x_{k-1} = x_k = 1$ and $x_{k+1} = 0$.
- $y_{k-1} = y_{k+1} = 1$ and $y_k = 0$.
- $z_{k-1} = 0$ and $z_k = z_{k+1} = 0$.

The majority of $x,y,z$ has $k+1$ many $1$'s, and so again the predicate is inexpressible.

If $n = k$ then you can use $x_1 \land \cdots \land x_n$, or $(x_1 \lor t) \land (x_1 \lor \lnot t) \land \cdots$ if you want the width to be exactly $2$.

If $(n,k) = (1,0)$ then you can use $\lnot x_1$ (or $(\lnot x_1 \lor t) \land (\lnot x_1 \lor \lnot t)$ if you want the width to be strictly $2$), and if $(n,k) = (2,1)$ then you can use $(x_1 \lor x_2) \land (\lnot x_1 \lor \lnot x_2)$.